# Can't understand SQLException when running rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a rails app, I am starting adding unit tests. My issue is that even When I run an empty test I have a SQLException :

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

The output is :

```
Run options: --seed 64346

# Running:

E

Error:
UserMailerTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: products: DELETE FROM "products"

bin/rails test test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:5

Finished in 0.233057s, 4.2908 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
```

There is no "products" table on my code. A `git grep -i product` gives me nothing.

Any help ?

Comment: What database is used in your database.yml under `test:` ?

Comment: The database is `db/test.sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the test folder for a fixture file called products.yml. If it's there and you don't have a products tabler, you'll get those errors because Rails is, by default, trying to populate your products table with data from that file.